# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - another "held broken packages" issue

Tags: package-management, dependencies, held-packages

Was trying to install "unity-tweak-tool" and get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Did some research and ran:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

then
    `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

but to no effect, so still got the problem of finding a way to backtrack to the cause of the dependencies. So tried aptitude and got:

```
sudo aptitude install unity-tweak-tool

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libhardware2{a} libhybris{a} libhybris-common1{a} libmedia1{a}
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin{a} liboxideqtcore0{ab} liboxideqtquick0{a}
  libqt5organizer5{ab} libubuntugestures5{ab} libubuntutoolkit5{ab}
  libunity-webapps0{a} qml-module-ubuntu-components{ab}
  qml-module-ubuntu-layouts{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-test{ab}
  qml-module-ubuntu-web{a} qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin{a}
  unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common{a} unity-webapps-qml{a}
  unity-webapps-service{a} webapp-container{ab} webbrowser-app{ab}
0 packages upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 36.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 145 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                    - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                                    - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
 liboxideqtcore0  : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                             - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
 libqt5organizer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
 webapp-container : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
                    Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5qml5, but 5.10.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build36 is installed.
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                   - libqt5qml5, but 5.10.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build36 is installed.
 qml-module-ubuntu-components : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                      - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                                         - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
                                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                          - libqt5qml5, but 5.10.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build36 is installed.
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                               - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                               - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
 webbrowser-app : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.                            - libqt5core5a, but 5.10.0+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build46 is installed.
              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - libqt5qml5, but 5.10.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build36 is installed.
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                - libqt5qml5, but 5.10.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build36 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:    
1)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                  
2)      liboxideqtcore0 [Not Installed]                        
3)      liboxideqtquick0 [Not Installed]                      
4)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                      
5)      libubuntugestures5 [Not Installed]                    
6)      libubuntutoolkit5 [Not Installed]                      
7)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                      
8)      qml-module-ubuntu-components [Not Installed]          
9)      qml-module-ubuntu-layouts [Not Installed]              
10)     qml-module-ubuntu-test [Not Installed]                
11)     qml-module-ubuntu-web [Not Installed]                  
12)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]
13)     unity-tweak-tool [Not Installed]                      
14)     unity-webapps-common [Not Installed]                  
15)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                      
16)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                  
17)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                      
18)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Attempting to work back through the dependencies, by installing manually also ran into issues with "`libqt5core5a`" when running `aptitude install liboxideqtquick0` wanting to uninstall `libmlt++3, libmlt6, libqt5webchannel5, melt, openshot, python-mlt and qt5-gtk-platformtheme`.

Any help tracking down a solution very much appreciated.
.

=========================================================================
Further to request for further info:

As there is some major lags in pkgs getting updated, the following have been added to get the latest versions of pkgs or install pkgs not in the main repositories. So, to be comprehensive I include the following.

I used a script to extract a list of the repos and PPAs:

The following are self explanatory:

```
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse'  
'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe'  
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse'  
'http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main'  
'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'  
'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib'
```

These are to get the latest versions OR add functionality:

```
ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases  
ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder  
ppa:webupd8team/nemo3   # latest version of nemo file browser  
ppa:linrunner/tlp  
ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests  
ppa:elementary-os/stable  
ppa:bablu-boy/nutty  
ppa:jfi/ppa  
ppa:audio-recorder/ppa  
ppa:noobslab/themes  
ppa:hda-me/zulucrypt  
ppa:scribus/ppa  
ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable  
ppa:mc3man/xerus-media  
ppa:unit193/encryption  
ppa:noobslab/icons  
ppa:jeffreyratcliffe/ppa  
'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main'   # Vivaldi Web Browser
```

===========
Now a detailed list of the installed pkgs from the PPAs, which I extracted using the following script:

```
apt-cache policy $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall$ | awk '{ print $1 }') | perl -e '@a = <>; $a=join("", @a); $a =~ s/\n(\S)/\n\n$1/g;  @packages = split("\n\n", $a); foreach $p (@packages) {print "$1: $2\n" if $p =~ /^(.*?):.*?500 http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/(.*?)\s/s}'
```

.

```
albatross-theme: noobslab/themes/ubuntu
ashes-theme: noobslab/themes/ubuntu
audio-recorder: audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu  
cinnamon-l10n: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
com.github.babluboy.nutty: bablu-boy/nutty/ubuntu  
contractor: elementary-os/stable/ubuntu  
cryptsetup: unit193/encryption/ubuntu  
cryptsetup-bin: unit193/encryption/ubuntu  
faba-icon-theme: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
faenza-icon-theme: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
faience-icon-theme: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
ffmpeg: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
gir1.2-nemo-3.0: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
gscan2pdf: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
handbrake-cli: stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu  
handbrake-gtk: stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu  
i965-va-driver: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
i965-va-driver: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libavcodec-extra: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavcodec-extra57: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavdevice-ffmpeg56: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavdevice57: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavfilter-ffmpeg5: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavfilter6: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavformat-ffmpeg56: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavformat57: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavresample-ffmpeg2: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavresample3: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavutil-ffmpeg54: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libavutil55: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libbasicusageenvironment1: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libcryptsetup4: unit193/encryption/ubuntu  
libfdk-aac1: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libglib-object-introspection-perl: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
libgoocanvas2-perl: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
libgranite-common: elementary-os/stable/ubuntu  
libgranite4: elementary-os/stable/ubuntu  
libgroupsock8: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libgtk3-perl: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
libgtk3-simplelist-perl: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
libimage-sane-perl: jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu  
liblirc-client0: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
liblircclient0: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
liblivemedia58: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libmysofa: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libnemo-extension1: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
libpostproc-ffmpeg53: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libpostproc54: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libqxp-0.0-0: scribus/ppa/ubuntu  
libswresample-ffmpeg1: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libswresample2: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libswscale-ffmpeg3: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libswscale4: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libusageenvironment3: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libva-drm1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libva-drm1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libva-x11-1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libva-x11-1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libva1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libva1: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
libvlc-bin: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libvlc5: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libvlccore8: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libx264-148: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libx264-152: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libx265-130: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libx265-146: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libxapp1: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
libzimg2: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
libzmf-0.0-0: scribus/ppa/ubuntu  
libzulucrypt1: hda-me/zulucrypt/ubuntu  
mpv: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
nemo: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
nemo-data: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
nemo-dropbox: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
nemo-fileroller: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
nemo-media-columns: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
numix-folders: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
numix-gtk-theme: noobslab/themes/ubuntu  
numix-icon-theme: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
numix-icon-theme-circle: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
numix-icon-theme-square: noobslab/icons/ubuntu  
nutty: bablu-boy/nutty/ubuntu  
psensor: jfi/ppa/ubuntu  
psensor-common: jfi/ppa/ubuntu  
python-nemo: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
scribus-ng: scribus/ppa/ubuntu  
scribus-ng-data: scribus/ppa/ubuntu  
scribus-ng-doc: scribus/ppa/ubuntu  
simplescreenrecorder: maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu  
simplescreenrecorder-lib: maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu  
smplayer: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
smplayer-themes: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
smtube: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
tlp: linrunner/tlp/ubuntu  
tlp-rdw: linrunner/tlp/ubuntu  
tp-smapi-dkms: linrunner/tlp/ubuntu # TLP Power Management, for Lenovo ThinkPad laptop  
uget: plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu  
va-driver-all: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
va-driver-all: mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu  
veracrypt: unit193/encryption/ubuntu  
vlc: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-bin: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-data: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-l10n: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-base: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-notify: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-qt: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-samba: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-skins2: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-video-output: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-video-splitter: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vlc-plugin-visualization: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
vokoscreen: mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu  
xapps-common: webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu  
zulucrypt-cli: hda-me/zulucrypt/ubuntu  
zulucrypt-gui: hda-me/zulucrypt/ubuntu
```

Comment: Have you checked actually held packages? https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/250300

Comment: Have seen that page and already tried those suggestions and quite a few others. Alas, the posting here ...

Comment: Is 16.04 LTS breaking down and not well maintained anymore?

Comment: Absolutely not, even 14.04 is still supported. You may have altered your environment using [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/250300), for example. Have you checked for actually held packages? Please [edit] your question to add the results. Also, have you any non-standard items in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? You can compare it to [generated contents](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

Comment: Updated with details of PPAs and packages, above ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)